# AJAX filling dropdown in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

So I have problem filling dropdown option with AJAX.

This is my JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sepatu").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var site_url = "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/pelanggan/dyos_sepatu/";
            $("#content").load(site_url);
        })
    })
</script>
```

that script is redictering to this controller

```
public function dyos_sepatu(){
        $data['jenis'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM jenis_sepatu")->result();
        $this->load->view('pelanggan/sepatu_dyos',true,$data);
    }
```

and this is my view (pelanggan/sepatu_dyos) loaded by the controller :

```
<select name="jenis" class="form-control">
            <?php
                foreach ($jenis as $data){?>
                <option value="<?php echo $data->id_jenis_sepatu;?>"><?php echo $data->nama_jenis;?></option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>
```

the dropdown value is doesnt show like this :

[image]

what is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try once like this...

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sepatu").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var site_url = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/pelanggan/dyos_sepatu/');?>";
            $("#content").load(site_url);
        })
    })
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function dyos_sepatu(){
        $jenis = $this->db->get('jenis_sepatu')->result();
        $this->load->view('pelanggan/sepatu_dyos',$jenis);
    }
```

Comment: is it just same but in different way ?

Comment: did you load `url` helper for using `base_url()`.

Comment: `print_r($jenis);` what is output? at controller.